# belongsToMany multiple foreign keys, laravel

Tags: laravel

Good morning

I currently have a table that is related to 3 tables.

It has occurred to me to do "belongsToMany", but I do not know how to do it with 3 relationships

Tables:

schools_series (relation)

- id
- cycle_id
- school_id
- serie_id

cycle

- id
- active (true / false)
- ** more columns **

school

- id
- ** more columns **

serie

- id
- ** more columns **

Principal Model:

School

class School extends Model implements Presentable
{
    use PresentableTrait;

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'network_id',
    'fantasy_name',
    'social_name',
    'email',
    'sim_web_code',
    'state_registration',
    'cnpj',
    'status',
    'start_date',
];

public function series()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Serie::class, 'schools_series')->where('id_cycle', 'xxxx');
}
```

I need to be able to take out the "school series" depending on the "cycle_id" that has "active" in cycle

example SQL:

```
SELECT ss.* FROM schools as s
INNER JOIN schools_series as ss
    ON ss.school_id = s.id
INNER JOIN cycle as c
    ON ss.cycle_id = c.id AND c.active = 1
WHERE s.id = 115
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: Hello Philipp, I need to be able to take out the "school series" depending on the "cycle_id" that has "active" in cycle

Comment: and what have you tried yet?
the docs explain really well how to do such queries

Comment: I want to do it inside "series of functions" and I do not know how to do it. I've given you an example in sql

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
public function series()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Serie::class, 'schools_series')->withPivot('cycle_id')->join('cycle', 'cycle.id', '=', 'schools_series.cycle_id')->where('cycle.active', '=', 1);
    }
```